# Network is not working nicely with RTL-8110SC/8169SC

Tags: 11.10, networking, filezilla

Well, I've got a wired network on my Ubuntu 11.10 fresh installation. I can download files and surf the Internet. The problem is that sometimes it takes a long time to load websites and sometimes it gives up trying. I also unsuccessfully tried to connect to an FTP server using Filezilla. The same wired network does work fine in a dual-boot installation of Windows 7.

How can I configure my network appropriately.

SOME INFO:

```
$ sudo lshw -class network  
*-network  
       description: Ethernet interface  
       product: RTL-8110SC/8169SC Gigabit Ethernet  
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.  
       physical id: 4  
       bus info: pci@0000:04:04.0  
       logical name: eth0  
       version: 10  
       serial: 00:1d:60:55:58:5c  
       size: 100Mbit/s  
       capacity: 1Gbit/s  
       width: 32 bits  
       clock: 66MHz  
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation  
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169   driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.135 latency=64 link=yes maxlatency=64 mingnt=32 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s  
       resources: irq:16 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:febfec00-febfecff memory:febc0000-febdffff
```

Comment: Could tell if your wired connection "auto configured" or if you manually set it up?

Comment: please have a look at this question and add some details of your hardware and some logs to your question.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Comment: It was auto configured. As I said, it does work, but not as well as it is supposed to.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to disable IPv6 if you are not using it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the kernel driver r8169 kernel is not good enough. Try compiling the ralink drivers:

1. Make a backup of your driver first. To find where the driver is:

   ```
   find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name r8169.ko
   ```

   copy the driver somewhere in your home directory.
2. Download the drivers [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=4&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#92) (select US1 server as the other two don't work)
3. Prepare the system for compiling:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) linux-source
   ```
4. Check whether the built-in driver, r8169.ko, is loaded.

   ```
   lsmod | grep r8169
   ```
5. If it is installed, please remove it.

   ```
   sudo modprobe -r r8169
   ```
6. compile the driver:

   ```
   tar jxvf r8169-6.015.00.tar.bz2 # unpack this on th desktop
   sudo mv r8169-6.015.00 /usr/src # move the drive directory from desktop to /usr/src
   sudo -i
   ```

   navigate to `/usr/src/r8169-6.015.00` and run

   ```
   make clean modules          
   make install
   depmod -a
   modprobe r8169
   ```

   drop privileges:

   ```
   exit
   ```
7. You can check whether the driver is loaded by using these commands:

   ```
   lsmod | grep r8169      
   ifconfig -a
   ```

   [image: lsmod output in terminal]
8. Reboot and check again that the driver is loaded. If it isn't, You might want to add r8169 to the list of modules which are loaded on startup. Edit this file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/modules
   ```

   add the line

   ```
   r8169
   ```

   save, exit, and reboot

If something goes wrong or you want to revert this procedure, just restore the file that you backed up in the first step to its original location.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious if you resolved this as i am having what i think is the same issue... network works fine for a moment, then will not respond at all for several minutes.  active connections seem to be ok since i downloaded source code for several hours without fail, but new connections seem to be the problem and only sometimes.

UPDATE: disabling ipv6 didnt work for me.  My solution for now was to install a spare Netgear 10/100 NIC in my motherboard until someone else fixes the realtek driver.

I have not tried hhlp's answer, but I needed this thing running ASAP so for now the spare card works great!

Comment: i have an integreated Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)

Comment: i tried hhlp's instructions and it worked.  I can't bump up his answer though... I had to download a different driver for my different adapter of course.